# page break doesn't work in CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have used this tag in my css:

```
@media print { 
  .page-break { page-break-inside: avoid; }
}
```

but why the selection split in different page?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside), `page-break-inside: avoid` tries to **avoid** the break *when possible*. As I understand from the screenshot you made, the page might be completely filled and/or the element is absolutely positioned, in which case `avoid` might/does not work.

You could instead try `break-before` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before)) to have the page break before the specific element starts, if your situation permits that.

Hope it helps!